# Display authenticated image

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, cors

I have two servers - one handling images and the other serving the main webpage. The main page needs to access images from the image server, including some private ones that require authentication. I am facing a challenge in figuring out how to send a request from the main server to the image server along with the authentication token.

The problem arises from the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policy because the request are restricted from including headers and cookies. Due to this, I am unable to include the authentication code in the request headers.

The image handling looks something like this, and it is working well. (Tested with Postman)

```
app.get("/:file", async (req, res) => {
  const filename = req.params.file
  const authorization = req.headers.authorization

  if (public.includes(filename)) {
    streamFile(res, `public/${filename}`)
  } else if (private.includes(filename) && authorization) {
    const valid = somethingThatCheckAuthorization(authorization)

    if (valid) {
        streamFile(res, `private/${filename}`)
    } else {
      return res.sendStatus(400)
    }
  } else {
    return res.sendStatus(400)
  }
})
```

How can I get an authenticated image to appear on a webpage?

Comment: Can you explain where the problem is exactly?  You are doing `const authorization = req.headers.authorization` but you say that CORS prevents the client from sending the authorization header to the main server?  So the other code (image server stuff) is irrelevant to the problem?  Please confirm.

Comment: I just want to know how to create a page where users can only view their own pictures. I would like to find a solution whereby the client can send a request to the server with their authentication details, and the server sends the image back to the client, which allows the client to display the image. The code snippet above is just an attempt. But unfortunately I see that this method does not work because of CORS policy. How do you think such a system could be implemented? The client side would look something like this:

Comment: $fetch("http://image.localhost/test.jpg", { headers: { Authorization: token } }).then(function (response) {
 const data = `data:${response.headers['content-type']};base64,${new Buffer(response.data).toString('base64')}`;this.setState({ imgSrc: data });
})